# Is there any way to build app bundle in Cordova or convert cordova singned apk file into app bundle

Tags: cordova, android-app-bundle

I have built an android app in Cordova and created the signed APK version too. But When I tried to release my app in the Google Playstore I found Google now does not allow the APK version. But I have no clue how to make an app bundle in Cordova.

Can anyone help me out so that I can create the app bundle to publish in the play store?

I have another question. I have two published apps. Should I have to upload the app bundle in the future for updates?

Comment: cordova build android --prod --release -- --packageType=bundle

Answer (score 0):

To generate a bundle, build your app with the flags `--release -- --packageType=bundle`

Yes in the future you should upload bundles